# If Else Condition For .Close?

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement

i got 2 forms 1mdiparent, 1child

lets say mdiparent = Form1 then child = Form2 .

i got New button in Form1 calling childform (Form2) like:

```
private void newDocument_ItemClick(object sender, ClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 formChild = new Form2();
            Form2.Show()
}
```

now my question was whats the if else condition for : if Form2 == Close?

something like:

```
if (Form2.Close == true){ //condition }

or if (Form2 == Close){ //condition }
```

but i know its not the right code .so hope you could help me :) thanks .

Comment: There is a relevant Form Closing event, i guess that is what you are looking out for

Comment: DO you want to be able to at any point ask if Form2 is open or closed or do you want to do something the moment Form2 has been closed?

Comment: @Chris i want to do something so i need it to be condition like: if Form2 is close; then a button in Form1 will be invisible ... something like that

Comment: your question is not clear...
now my question was whats the if else condition for : if Form2 == Close?

something like:

if (Form2.Close == true){ //condition }

or if (Form2 == Close){ //condition } ..??

Comment: @GAPS this is the main question sir: now my question was whats the if else condition for : if Form2 == Close? // follow up text was just an example to make it clearer .

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be notified by the system when the Form2 is closed so you could apply some internal logic to avoid the reopening of the child form and apply some kind of changes to your main interface.
If this is your problem then you could add your event handler for the FormClosing event of the Form2 directly in the code of Form1 when you open the Form2

```
// Flag to keep the state open/close of the child form
private bool childClosed = true;

private void newDocument_ItemClick(object sender, ClickEventArgs e)
{
    if(childClosed == true)
    {
        Form2 formChild = new Form2();
        // Setup the event handler form the Form2 closing directly here in the MDI
        formChild.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(myFormClosing);
        formChild.Show();

        // set the flag to avoid the reopening
        childClosed = false;
    }
}

// Now, when the formChild closes, you will receive the event directly here in the MDI
private void myFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // The child form is closing......
    // Do your update here, but first check the close reason

    if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
    {
       ......
       // reset the flag so you could reopen the child if needed
       childClosed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ill try all answers tomorrow sir and will accept it when it worked thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use either the `Form.FormClosed` event or the `Form.FormClosing` event. Probably the former since you don't really want to interact with the closing of the form.

You would create a method and have it called when the event is fired and this would do whatever you wanted (such as hide buttons and such like).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx for details of the formclosed event.

Answer (score 1):

When a form is closed, it's disposed too. Thus just check if it's disposed by following code:

```
Form2 formChild = new Form2();
// ...
if (formChild.IsDisposed) {
    // Do someting
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @V4Vendetta pointed out: there is a `FormClosing` event (called before the form has closed. Used to tell the user "You haven't saved yet") and a `FormClosed` event (called after the form closed).

```
public class Form2 : Form
{
    public bool hasClosed;

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        hasClosed = true;
    }
}
```

with this, you can do

```
if (formChild.hasClosed)
    // do something
```

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to take this approach, the Form 2 is initialized in the button click event, therefore, you assume that the form object was not available.

if you want to change this order, then the form should be initialized somewhere else like  the constructor of the Form 1.

```
private Form2 form2;
public Form1()
{
    form2 = new Form2();
}

private void newDocument_ItemClick(object sender, ClickEventArgs e)
{
    if(!form2.Visible)
    {
        form2.Show();
    }else
    {
        form2.Hide();
    }
}
```

Hiding a form is not same as closing a form, if you really open and close the form2 and carry out some action based on that, then you should set a property on the parent form when the form2 closing event is triggered, to do this you must pass the parent form as an argument in the form2 constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that with the help of the following code

```
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
{
        if (f.Text == formName)
        {
                    IsOpen = true;
                    break;
        }
}
if(!IsOpen)
{....do your code....}
```